# How to turn selected features from Random Forest into a new list

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am working on a regression problem.  For my model, I am using the Random Forest Classifier for dimensionality reduction.  The output is a space-separated string of boolean values which highlight the good features as "True".  This is what it looks like:

```
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True False  True  True False  True  True  True False  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False  True False False  True
  True False False False False False False False False False False  True
 False False  True False False False False False False  True False False
 False  True False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False  True False False  True False False
 False  True False  True False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False  True False False False False False False False False  True False
 False False False False False  True False False False  True  True False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False  True False False False False False
 False False  True False False  True False  True False  True False False
  True False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False  True False  True False  True False False False False
 False False False False False  True  True False False False False False
 False False False False  True False  True  True False  True False False
 False False False  True  True  True False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False  True False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False  True False False False
 False  True False]
```

So what I've done is turn this into a comma-separated list like this:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]
```

and then loop through each element and retrieve the corresponding test column.  This is the entire code for this process:

```
sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100), threshold = '1.25*mean')
sel.fit(x_train, y_train)

selected = sel.get_support()
selected_list = list(selected)
columns_list = []

for i in range(len(selected_list)):
    if(selected_list[i] == 'True'):
        columns_list.append(test[i])

print(columns_list)
```

But now I get an empty list despite trying to append it to my `columns_list`.  Basically, my goal is to use the columns from dimensionality reduction in my prediction.  I am using Linear Regression for this problem.

**Update**

When I change my code to the suggestion below, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2890, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/Documents/Boston-Kaggle/Model.py", line 100, in <module>
    columns_list.append(test[i])
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2975, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2892, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(selected_list[i] == 'True'):
    columns_list.append(test[i])
```

You are comparing a boolean against a string value `'True'` instead of `True`

A compact and pythonic solution would be:

```
 if selected_list[i]:
    columns_list.append(test[i])
```

For your second error, that's because you are accessing a dataframe  `test` with `[]`. You need to use the method `.iloc`

For the usage, it depends on what test contains:

```
test.iloc[0] # first row of data frame- Note a Series data type output.
test.iloc[1] # second row of data frame 
test.iloc[-1] # last row of data frame 
# Columns:
test.iloc[:,0] # first column of data frame 
test.iloc[:,1] # second column of data frame 
test.iloc[:,-1] # last column of data frame
```

Edit, a more explicit solution:

```
columns_selected = test.iloc[:, [i for i in range(len(selected_list)) if selected_list[i]]]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate the `.iloc` if you don't mind?  How should I modify the code?

Comment: @OnurOzbek it depends on what you want to select from test. Check my updates

Comment: I want to select each index which is true.

Comment: @OnurOzbek yes but columns or rows? I suppose row, because test is probably a matrix, and the features are on the columns

Comment: Let me clarify:  From the test dataset, I want to select every column where `selected_list` rings True.

Comment: @OnurOzbek than in my updates you can find the answer.

Comment: I did this: `columns_list.append(test.iloc[:,i])` and I get this error: `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: @OnurOzbek check again my answer

Comment: Gives the exact same `IndexError`

Comment: I don't know the shape of your dataframe :)

Comment: try to use iloc on x_train instead

Comment: columns_selected = x_train.iloc[:, [i for i in range(len(selected_list)) if selected_list[i]]]

Comment: But why?  x_train is less amount of columns than train or test.

Comment: No, training set and test set should have the same amount of columns (features) before you apply the feature selection. Anyway, I cannot see where you load the test data frame

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
columns_list = list(x_train.columns[selected_list])
selected_test = test[columns_list]
```

In this way, you retrieve the names of the selected columns from `x_train`, put them in `column_list`, and search them in `test`. This should work even if train and test data do not have same amount of columns; obviously it wont work if test data does not have one of the selected features.

Comment: Thanx man. I've just upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?